# Prevent bootstrap popover from disappearing after postback

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, popover

I have a boostrap popover with asp checkboxes. Autopostback is set to true for checboxes because I want to show columns in my girdview depending on the checkboxes checked. I have 5 properties in one gridview column hence sorting on gridview rows will not work without using a popover. How to keep bootstrap popover from disappearing after postbacks and also maintain checkbox state. All of this stuff is wrapped inside an UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a javascript function to display the popover

```
function openPopover() {
    $('#chkBox').popover('show');
    return false;
}
```

Then on server side in the autopostback you will have to call code to display the popover again after the postback for the checkbox.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openPopover();", true);
```

Comment: Oh I am aware of the modal pop up. I am facing that issue with bootstrap popover.

Comment: Updated my answer, it should be the same idea show the popover. You will have to call javascript to re display it.